# how can I send a variable to println?

Tags: arduino-uno, print

this is my method

```
void mensaje_sms()
{   
  string numero = "777777";  // this is my variable           
  SIM900.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");
  delay(100);
      SIM900.println("AT+CMGS=\"591"numero"\"");
//IM900.println("AT+CMGS=\"59177777777\""); //only in this way does it work
      delay(100);
      SIM900.println("SEND NUMERO VARIABLE RODO");
      delay(100);
      SIM900.println((char)26);
      delay(100);
      SIM900.println();
      delay(5000);
      Serial.println("SMS sent successfully");
    }
```

***how can I send a variable to println?***

Comment: What variable? What do you want to happen?

Comment: this is my variable `int numero = 777777;` I need to put that in the println

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
SIM900.println("AT+CMGS=\"591"numero"\"");
```

to

```
SIM900.print("AT+CMGS=\"591");
SIM900.print(numero);
SIM900.println("\"");
```

Note that only the final call is to `println()` (which just prints a carriage-return character at the end.)